# A way to open up Slack Search UI (in a browser) from a URL

Tags: slack

I was trying to see if there was a way to open up the new Slack Search UI, in a browser, from a URL.

For example, in Microsoft Teams, you can open up the following link https://teams.microsoft.com/_#/apps/a2da8768-95d5-419e-9441-3b539865b118/search?q=yourQueryHere in a new tab, and it would open up your Teams and open up the search UI with yourQueryHere results already listed.

Is there something similar for Slack? So far I do not believe it is possible because Slack does not have routes for search pages.

Let's say we are here: https://company.slack.com/messages/channelId/.
We then type something in the search bar and press search. The URL stays constant.

Note that Slack seems (?) to have deeplinking for search (slack://) according to their docs, but there are no examples (I tried slack://search/hello, slack://search).

Answer (score 10):

It seems that the last parameter from the search URL -`https://app.slack.com/client/.../search/search-eyJ...` - is Base64 encoding over a JSON string:

```json
{
  "d": "search query goes here",
  "q": "... (not sure what this is used for, can be disregarded)",
  "r": "search query goes here"
}
```

So I'm using this method and it works fine:

```py
# search.py
import sys
import base64
import os
import json
from urllib.parse import quote

query = sys.argv[1]
search_data = json.dumps({
    "d": quote(query),
    "r": quote(query)
})
qhash = base64.b64encode(search_data.encode()).decode()
url = f'https://app.slack.com/client/.../search/search-{qhash}'

os.system(f'open "" {url}')
```

And then:

```bash
./search.py "my search query"
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work anymore - at least for me it just opens the last search i did

Comment: I just tested it again, for me it still works fine. Maybe something wrong on your end? Try to clean cache or similar.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same question for Slack support earlier - it looks like they removed Slack deep search linking via the `slack://search` URL after they released their new search functionality:

> I am sorry to report that we currently do not support search deep linking at the moment. We previously did but it needed to be removed while our improved search was being worked on and released.
>
> The docs you linked to used to have a better description further up the page about how to use this deep link and the required syntax. It looks like the example workflows section you link to is a remnant of that.
>
> I am really sorry that the docs mislead you. I will contact the API docs team and ask them to remove those references. Hopefully in the future we can reinstate this ability once again.

Comment: That answers the desktop-side of things, thank you! And since the browser side has no GET route for search pages, there is no way to deep link in both browser and desktop, right? I was wondering if that should be included in the answer as well for completion.

Comment: I can't confirm 100% for the browser side of things, but I did try things like `team.slack.com/search?q=abc` and a few others with no luck. It might be worth asking Support to confirm this.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm afraid to say that there's no way at the moment to do what you describe, but it's a pretty cool idea! I'm not sure how we could cleanly manage such a change in light of our recent adjustments to the search UI (it's not in the side pane anymore!), but I'll pass your desire for such a thing along to the rest of the team here.
>   Thanks for writing in about this! Please let me know if you happen to think of anything similar you'd like to see changed or added to the app, and I'll be happy to make sure the right folks hear about it.

I've sent a message to the Slack team, and they've responded extremely fast. Unfortunately, there is no way at the moment.